# INotifyCollectionChanged is not updating the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a class as shown below. All the functions I have removed for brevity

```
public class PersonCollection:IList<Person>
{}
```

Now I have one more Model class as shown below. AddValueCommand is class deriving from ICommand which again I am omiting.

```
public class DataContextClass:INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private PersonCollection personCollection = PersonCollection.GetInstance();

    public IList<Person> ListOfPerson
    {
        get 
        {
            return personCollection;
        }            
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        personCollection.Add(person);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
    }


    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = delegate { };
    public void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action));
        }
    }       

    ICommand addValueCommand;

    public ICommand AddValueCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (addValueCommand == null)
            {
                addValueCommand = new AddValueCommand(p => this.AddPerson(new Person { Name = "Ashish"}));
            }
            return addValueCommand;               
        }
    }
}
```

In the main window I am binding my UI to Model as shown below

```
 DataContextClass contextclass = new DataContextClass();           
 this.DataContext = new DataContextClass();
```

And My UI looks like as shown below

```
<ListBox Margin="5,39,308,113" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfPerson}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Button"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding Path=AddValueCommand}" Margin="233,39,0,73" />
```

My List Box is not updating with the new value when button is clicked. What I am missing here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`INotifyCollectionChanged` has to be implemented by a collection class. Not by the class *containing*  the collection.
You need to remove `INotifyPropertyChanged` from `DataContextClass` and add it to `PersonCollection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Answers, but here I have a doubt suppose if I dont want to change my PersonCollection, how can I achieve this by only doing the change at DataContextClass

Comment: @Vikram: You can't. The WPF engine looks for that interface on the property that is bound to `ItemsSource`. It doesn't look for that interface on the data context.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `IList` use `ObservableCollection<T>` and define your `PersonCollection` class as below:

```
public class PersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person>
{}
```

You can read more about `ObservableCollection<T>` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is designed specifically for collection change notifications in WPF DataBinding scenarios.

As you can see from the definition in *MSDN* below, it already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

More articles to help you with usage of ObservableCollection class in WPF are below:

[Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx)
[An introduction to ObservableCollection in Wpf](http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/an-introduction-to-observablecollection-in-wpf/)
[Databinding a ObservableCollection in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762656/databinding-a-observablecollectiont-in-mvvm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I will not be able to do changes in PersonCollection.