# How to refresh ICollectionView when new item added into it's internal ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, datagridview, observablecollection, icollectionview

Please see my code below

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> testList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> TestList
    {
        get { return testList; }
        set
        {
            if (testList != value)
            {
                testList = value;
                SetProperty<ObservableCollection<Person>>(ref testList, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private ListCollectionView personListView;

    public ICollectionView PersonListView
    {
        get
        {
            if (personListView == null)
            {
                personListView = new ListCollectionView(TestList)
                {
                    Filter = p => FilterPerson((Person)p)
                };
            }
            return personListView;
        }

    }
```

I want to know how to update PersonListView and refresh UI when new item is inserted into TestList, or the whole TestList is re-assigned? I've tried call Refresh method in TestList set method, but when a new item is inserted into the collection, set method will not be invoked.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297983/inotifycollectionchanged-is-not-updating-the-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add a collection changed event to the TestList observable collection and filter the PersonListView in it.

```
     TestList.CollectionChanged += TestList_CollectionChanged;

     void TestList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                {
                    /// Filter the PersonListView
                }
            }
```